# Tensorflow graph getting too big

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I am currently using Tensorflow for a deep learning application I'm developing at work. I can't go into specifics about the application, but the code is something like a customized Word2Vec, but the cost for each word-vector-representation needs to be computed individually. :

```
def cost_function(word_vector, other_word_vectors):
    # cost for a single training example needs to be computed
    # separately, and it depends on the vector representations
    # of some other words, depending on the training instance
    return tf.nn.tanh(some_mathematical_computation)
```

The problem with this approach is that the graph size tends to blow up so much, that the `compute_gradients` operation takes a lot of time. Not only that, the time taken to `compute_gradients` increases linearly with the graph size. `tf.stop_gradients` does not help for some reason. What does help is initializing a new `tf.Graph` and a new `tf.Session()` for every few training instances (call this a mini-batch), performing multiple such computations in parallel (call this a mini-batch-collection), and then combining the results and saving them for the next mini-batch-collection.

```
def learning(mini_batch):
     with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            self.perform_learning_on_batch(mini_batch, sess)
            return resultant_model 

def collection_learn(mini_batch_collection):
    models = run_learning_in_parallel()
    return combine_model(models)

def master():
   initial_model = something
   for mini_batch_collection in dataset:
       new_model = collection_learn(mini_batch_collection)
```

Is there a better way to perform parallel learning for such an application?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically creating TensorFlow graphs will not be as efficient as reusing the graph. Without looking at your code it's hard to say more, but folding all of the conditional logic into TensorFlow will make this problem go away. Failing that, trying to somehow cache the generated graphs should also help.

Comment: Thanks... I ended using a simple implementation of downpour gradient descent. Couldn't get around it with tensorflow. Any idea if a dynamic graph framework (like pytorch) would help?

Comment: Downpour gradient descent is what tensorflow models use by default for distributed and parallel training.